# Newly created partition number

Tags: partition, java, parted

I'm writing a program (in java) that slices a clean device onto a set of partitions, using `parted mkpart` to create the partitions. In order to create a next partition, I want to know a partition number that the program have just created. Current implementation is reading all existing partitions (using sfdisk) and calculates the last one - this is very inefficient and becomes very slow after creating a few dozen partitions.

I found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491348/220545) that suggests using `parted print free`, but that doesn't fit quite well to my case: 1) there can be holes of free spaces, so I may actually get not the last created partition; 2) because the partitioning is being done programmatically (in java) it's tricky to parse the `parted print free` output (unless there is a json option, which I didn't find).

Is there a way to know right away what partition number has just been created?

Comment: it's not json but there is `--machine`, `displays machine parseable output`. or you can also go through `/sys/block/sdx/sdx*/{start,size}`

Comment: Thank you, @frostschutz! Is it available and has the same format on all major Unix based Operating Systems?